# Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 can't get remote

Tags: vnc, xrdp

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and cannot manage to get a remote desktop connection with Windows.

Both computers all on the same wifi network.

I made the first attempt with VNC. On Ubuntu I have enabled the remote access. On VNC I have entered the correct address of the Ubuntu computer. The first screens will display and  ask for my credentials, then everything will close without any error.

Since VNC was not working, I made a second attempt with XRDP. I have installed XRDP with apt-get and have it running.

I try to start with remote desktop and had exactly the same behavior. The first screens will display and  ask for my credentials, then one second of the back window and everything will close without any error. Additionally on the Ubuntu screen I am not able to display the terminal again anymore, it just refuses to open and the cursor spins forever.

I would appreciate to get instructions on how to find the cause for this behavior. what would be the logs, that I could analyze?
Regards and best thanks
Laszlo

The Windows side must be okay, I am connecting to other computers (e.g. Raspberry pis) without any flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had trouble with remote session on 18.04 and am still looking for a usable solution.  It was possible to get a remote access once the ~/.xsession was modified to contain the following one line:
env -u SESSION_MANAGER -u DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS xfce4-session

The first two of the following three step process is required every time the system is booted.  The third step is the step that makes a successful remote connection and, it is possible time after time until next system boot:
1. Start a remote desktop connection, selecting the Xvnc protocol (it results in a moveable mouse but the screen is grey)
2. Using a putty session (or any other telnet), find the recently started xfce4-session process and kill it.
3. Start a remote desktop connection, selecting the Xorg protocol.

At first, I disabled the firewall (ufw).
Later, I enabled the firewall then immediately put in the necessary rules allowing my LAN to access the remote Xubuntu system using port 3389.